# Average power dissipated as the heat in the resistor

Tags: circuit-analysis

I’m trying to calculate the average power dissipated as the heat in the resistor.

A 12 V amplitude sinusoidal signal is applied across a 500 ohm resistor.

I have determined the current amplitude to be 0.024 A and the root mean square to be 16.97 mA.

I use P = I x V = 0.024 x 12 = 0.288 W

Where P is the power, I is the current and V is the voltage.

Is this correct ?

Comment: No. You need to multiply RMS values of both current and voltage.

Comment: So it should be 0.144 W ?

Comment: "12V amplitude" - is that 12Vrms, peak, or peak-peak?

Comment: @Reinderien - or average (mean )?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast unlikely. Since there is no mention of a DC rail, the mean would be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With AC the real power is

[image]

(From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power#Alternating_current)

Cosθ is 1 because you have resisitive load.

Thus you have to calculate with RMS values.

Note that power can also be calculated as

[image]

(From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power#Resistive_circuits)

and RMS voltage is

[image: RMS voltage]

(From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square)

Thus your power is [image]